# Manifest.xml Error

Tags: android, xml

I am working on a project that I just started in Android SDK.  In Manifest.xml, I can't find the error that it is saying that it has.  The error is:

```
[2013-03-10 12:34:22 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper]   Parser exception for C:\Users\Zac\workspace\SlenderAR\AndroidManifest.xml: Attribute "name" bound to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was already specified for element "uses- permission".
```

My Manifest.xml file contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.slenderar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
        android:name="android.permission.FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true"
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass" android:required="true"
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="true"
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.slenderar.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your block

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
    android:name="android.permission.FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Should be

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Only one name is allowed in each permission block.  Similar things can be said about the uses-feature blocks.

Comment: Thank you!  I am not very experienced with developing for android, and never really preferred XML as a markup language.  I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Do not combine two permissions with each other:

Try this code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove also

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

and replace your old permissions with the right code syntax

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sqlitenew.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```